# Can't update to 8.9.1 after migrating from webflo/drupal-core-strict to drupal/core-recommended

Tags: composer

I successfully updated my drupal 8.7.8 site to 8.9.0 following the instructions on 'Migrate composer project for Drupal earlier than 8.8.0' Drupal documentation page, section 'Migrating from webflo/drupal-core-strict to drupal/core-recommended'.

```
    composer update # To update any dependencies as a separate step.
    git add composer.lock; git commit # Save the updates as a separate commit.
    composer remove webflo/drupal-core-strict --no-update
    composer remove drupal/core --no-update
    composer require 'composer/installers:^1.7' --no-update
    rm composer.lock
    rm -rf vendor # Also helps avoid conflicts.
    composer require drupal/core-recommended:^8.8 --update-with-dependencies
    git add composer.json composer.lock; git commit -m "Update Drupal to 8.8.0 and use drupal/core-recommended instead of webflo/drupal-core-strict"
```

Now I can't update drupal to 8.9.1.

I execute the command

```
composer update drupal/core-recommended --with-dependencies

> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Package webflo/drupal-core-require-dev is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use drupal/core-dev instead.
Generating autoload files
38 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles
```

To check if the my project now uses drupal/core-recommended I executed

```
composer show drupal/core-recommended

name     : drupal/core-recommended
descrip. : Locked core dependencies; require this project INSTEAD OF drupal/core.
keywords :
versions : * 8.9.0
type     : metapackage
license  : GNU General Public License v2.0 or later (GPL-2.0-or-later) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-2.0-or-later.html#licenseText
homepage :
source   : [git] https://github.com/drupal/core-recommended.git 1b87cf5dea633a66a1c4f22d635bc92c127071d9
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/drupal/core-recommended/zipball/1b87cf5dea633a66a1c4f22d635bc92c127071d9 1b87cf5dea633a66a1c4f22d635bc92c127071d9
path     : /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d8composer
names    : drupal/core-recommended

requires
asm89/stack-cors 1.3.0
composer/semver 1.5.1
doctrine/annotations v1.4.0
doctrine/cache v1.6.2
doctrine/collections v1.4.0
doctrine/common v2.7.3
doctrine/inflector v1.2.0
doctrine/lexer 1.0.2
drupal/core 8.9.0
easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.1
egulias/email-validator 2.1.17
guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.4
guzzlehttp/promises v1.3.1
guzzlehttp/psr7 1.6.1
laminas/laminas-diactoros 1.8.7p2
laminas/laminas-escaper 2.6.1
laminas/laminas-feed 2.12.2
laminas/laminas-stdlib 3.2.1
laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge 1.0.4
masterminds/html5 2.3.0
paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99
pear/archive_tar 1.4.9
pear/console_getopt v1.4.3
pear/pear-core-minimal v1.10.10
pear/pear_exception v1.0.1
psr/container 1.0.0
psr/http-message 1.0.1
psr/log 1.1.3
ralouphie/getallheaders 3.0.3
stack/builder v1.0.5
symfony-cmf/routing 1.4.1
symfony/class-loader v3.4.41
symfony/console v3.4.41
symfony/debug v3.4.41
symfony/dependency-injection v3.4.41
symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.41
symfony/http-foundation v3.4.41
symfony/http-kernel v3.4.41
symfony/polyfill-ctype v1.17.0
symfony/polyfill-iconv v1.17.0
symfony/polyfill-intl-idn v1.17.0
symfony/polyfill-mbstring v1.17.0
symfony/polyfill-php56 v1.17.0
symfony/polyfill-php70 v1.17.0
symfony/polyfill-php72 v1.17.0
symfony/polyfill-util v1.17.0
symfony/process v3.4.41
symfony/psr-http-message-bridge v1.1.2
symfony/routing v3.4.41
symfony/serializer v3.4.41
symfony/translation v3.4.41
symfony/validator v3.4.41
symfony/yaml v3.4.41
twig/twig v1.42.5
typo3/phar-stream-wrapper v3.1.4

conflicts
webflo/drupal-core-strict *
```

I executed the command

```
composer prohibits drupal/core:8.9.1

drupal/core-recommended         8.9.0  requires  drupal/core (8.9.0)
webflo/drupal-core-require-dev  8.9.0  requires  drupal/core (8.9.0)
```

my composer.json file is

```
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.7",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
        "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.2",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^2.2",
        "drupal/backup_migrate": "^4.0",
        "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.9",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.2",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.5",
        "drupal/token": "^1.5",
        "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
        "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "^8.7.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": ["load.environment.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "drupal-scaffold": "DrupalComposer\\DrupalScaffold\\Plugin::scaffold",
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how solve this issue.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty new with Composer, so take this advice with some skepticism.

I think the problem is you deleted drupal/core:

composer remove drupal/core

I looked in my composer.lock, and found drupal/core-recommended requires drupal/core. (I think maybe drupal/core-recommended is a metapackage that encompasses drupal/core.)

Look at the results of the "prohibits" command. "core-recommended" requires "core".

Hope that helps,
Bill

Comment: Hello Bill,thank you very much for your message.

Comment: composer remove drupal/core was part of the Drupal documentation instructions to migrate from webflo/drupal-core-strict to drupal/core-recommended.
Thanks to those commands I could successfully update my site from 8.7.8  to 8.9.0.

I made a check on my composer.lock file and I didn't find drupal/core-recommended requires drupal/core.

I suspect my problem is caused by webflo which, probably, is still active.
Best regards. Paolo